# Android Things Bluetooth Le permissions

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to debug may Android Things BLE app in Android Studio. I am trying to do a simple scan on my main activity thread but I keep getting this exception:

```
01-17 02:13:24.735 29032-29044/com.dv.iotitag W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
                                                    java.lang.SecurityException: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results
                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
                                                        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.startScan(IBluetoothGatt.java:920)
                                                        at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper.onScannerRegistered(BluetoothLeScanner.java:442)
                                                        at android.bluetooth.le.IScannerCallback$Stub.onTransact(IScannerCallback.java:56)
                                                        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
```

I have the permissions in the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dv.iotitag">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.MANAGE_INPUT_DRIVERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.MANAGE_BLUETOOTH" />

<application>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things" />

    <service
        android:name="com.dv.androidthings.ble.common.BluetoothLeService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

but I still keep getting the exception in debug mode. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From API 23 (Android 6.0) it is not sufficient to declare permisions in `Manifest.xml`. You have to request them in runtime as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: I assumed this but the runtime permissions sample do not seem valid for AndroidThings (API 26). You can't declare MainActivity extends from AppCompat. Any idea on how to do this in "things"?

Comment: try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" required="true"/>` and analogically for `FINE_LOCATION`

Comment: And also "Dangerous permissions requested by apps are not granted until the next device reboot. This includes new app installs and new elements in existing apps"

Comment: I tried adding the permissions (static and runtime). The reboot is giving me issues as I am trying to run interactive "debug" so I can step through my code. I am not sure how to do this an keep my debugging session

Answer (score 0):

Go to your applications inside your phone and make sure your have location enabled and have it turned  on.

In you oncreate method call:
checkPermission();

`public void checkPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {`

                `//
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,}, 1);
            }
        }
    }`